# Issue with Filters in Custom QuerySets mongoengine

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongoengine

I have a MongoEngine model `Place`

```py
class Place(Document):
    is_favorite = fields.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = fields.StringField(max_length=150)
    price_tier = fields.IntField(min_value=1, max_value=3)

    meta = {
    'queryset_class': AwesomerQuerySet
    }
```

I'm using [Custom QuerySets](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#custom-querysets) from MongoEngine.

```py
class AwesomerQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def getNinePlaces1(self):
        #the below line returns empty queryset
        qSet = self.filter(price_tier=2)[:9]
        return qSet

    def getNinePlaces2(self):
        #the below line returns proper queryset
        qSet = self.filter(is_favorite=True)[:9]
        return qSet
```

Output:

```
print(Place.objects.getNinePlaces1())
>> []

print(Place.objects.getNinePlaces2())
>> [<Place: Place object>, <Place: Place object>, <Place: Place object>, <Place: Place object>, <Place: Place object>, <Place: Place object>, <Place: Place object>, <Place: Place object>, <Place: Place object>]
```

Issue:
I'm not sure why Place.objects.getNinePlaces1() is returning an empty set. Please help me understand.

Let me know if I'm not clear. Thanks!

Comment: Probably because you don't have docs in your collection which match  condition `price_tier=2`?

Comment: I wish that was the case. But, I have them!

Comment: But a breakpoint at `qSet = self.filter(price_tier=2)[:9]` and debug what the query returns.